# Jquery list drag & drop issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

i am using jquery sortable and i am facing an issue . when i drag a list its shows me a big blank space.
this is my code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#todo").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {

        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings'

        $.post("todo/updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){

        });                                                              
    }                                 
    });
});
```

html

```
<ul id="todo">
<?php

$sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `todo` WHERE `proid`='$proid' ORDER BY `order` ASC");
 $b=mysql_num_rows($sel);
 $i=0;
while($show=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
    $i++;
?>
<li id="recordsArray_<?php echo $show['id']; ?>"><div class="span12"><em><strong><?php echo $show['title'] ?></strong></em></li>

<?php
}
?>
<?ul>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you put an example in to a http://jsfiddle.net? It's a much easier to see whats going there than in a picture.

Comment: Its working fine in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4t6sX/ why not working fine in my project?

Comment: If it works in a fiddle and not in your code, then it is being affected by something you did not add to the fiddle. Probably CSS.

Comment: i think your css file creating the issue or js files. have alook on it. remove one by one and check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your css file creating the issue or js files. have alook on it. remove one by one and check it.